# adding a prefix word to each line in a text file

Tags: file, text, line, each, prefix

I have a text file with differnt names on it
Albert
Peter
Sam
Eric
joel

I need to add Mr. before each name in each line in the file using bash. Please guide. Thank you.

I tried with variable but I am not sure how to use on a file.